# error to execute djangocms -f -p . mysite

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a problem when I execute `djangocms -f -p . mysite`
the process started but failed when it have to create an  admin user.

```
Creating admin user
/Users/ccsguest/Site/djangoProject/django1101/bin/python2.7: can't open file 'create_user.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
The installation has failed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ccsguest/Site/djangoProject/django1101/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Users/ccsguest/Site/djangoProject/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 41, in execute
    django.setup_database(config_data)
  File "/Users/ccsguest/Site/djangoProject/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/django/__init__.py", line 394, in setup_database
    create_user(config_data)
  File "/Users/ccsguest/Site/djangoProject/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/django/__init__.py", line 411, in create_user
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'create_user.py'], env=env)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/ccsguest/Site/djangoProject/django1101/bin/python2.7', u'create_user.py']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

The process created the folder with the project and inside I have all the normally files and folder but there is a  file call create_user.py, and when I run the server I see the page for login but I never define user and password

My environment has this configuration

```
cmsplugin-filer==1.1.3
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.8.15
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-classy-tags==0.8.0
django-cms==3.4.0
django-filer==1.2.5
django-formtools==1.0
django-mptt==0.8.6
django-polymorphic==0.8.1
django-sekizai==0.10.0
Django-Select2==4.3.2
django-treebeard==4.0.1
djangocms-admin-style==1.2.4
djangocms-attributes-field==0.1.1
djangocms-column==1.7.0
djangocms-googlemap==0.5.2
djangocms-installer==0.9
djangocms-link==2.0.1
djangocms-snippet==1.9.1
djangocms-style==1.7.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor==3.2.1
djangocms-video==2.0.2
easy-thumbnails==2.3
html5lib==0.9999999
Pillow==3.3.1
pytz==2016.6.1
six==1.10.0
South==1.0.2
tzlocal==1.2.2
Unidecode==0.4.19
```

any idea how to fix the problem!

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Adding '-w' did the trick for me:

`source venv/bin/activate`
`mkdir project_name`
`cd project_name`
`djangocms -w -f -p . project_name`

Comment: but don't work for me, I try this option too. (Don't recognize -w command) The problem is that this environment worked fine, the last project that I create I select Django version  1.5.12 and Django CMS version 2.4.2 , this project produce the fail, I suppose that because after that work perfectly. I have other environment and works perfectly, the different that I see is  that the environment that no work has Django CMS version 3.4.0, the environment that works has Django CMS version 3.2.5

Comment: Works for me with Django CMS **3.4.0** and Django **1.8.15**!