# Creating new project using DjangoCMS

Tags: django-cms

Im trying to create a new project using DJango CMS but have this problem.

```
Creating admin user
/Users/p/.virtualenvs/cms/bin/python: can't open file 'create_user.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
The installation has failed.
```

Comment: Hello, We've released a new version that fixes this (0.9.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same error on Oct 1st and got is solved thanks to :
[error to execute djangocms -f -p . mysite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752641/error-to-execute-djangocms-f-p-mysite)

credit : s.benve

> I had the same issue.
>   Adding '-w' did the trick for me:
>   [...]
>     djangocms -w -f -p . project_name

my versions :
django-cms==3.4.0
django==1.8.14

Comment: THanks..I dont get that error anymore but get this error now...    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.